# RxJava: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError

Tags: android, exception, rx-java, onerror, rx-android

I am getting a IllegalStateException error in the Rx Library and don't know exactly where the root of the issue is, whether it is with RxJava or something I may be doing incorrectly.

The fatal crash occurs when certificate pinning (occurs on all server requests) but seems to point to a session timeout or logout and back in. Repro steps (occures about 25% of the time) are as follows: login, open list item - scroll all the way end - logout - logback in - open app - close app -> Crash!

Anyone have any ideas on how to prevent this? I found a similar issue here [Observer.onError firing off inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860942/observer-onerror-firing-off-inconsistently)

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fatal Exception thrown on Scheduler.Worker thread.
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:62)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorFailedException: Error occurred when trying to propagate error to Observer.onError
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:201)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:159)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException: 2 exceptions occurred. 
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber._onError(SafeSubscriber.java:201)
   at rx.observers.SafeSubscriber.onError(SafeSubscriber.java:111)
   at rx.internal.operators.OperatorObserveOn$ObserveOnSubscriber$2.call(OperatorObserveOn.java:159)
   at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
Caused by: rx.exceptions.CompositeException$CompositeExceptionCausalChain: Chain of Causes for CompositeException In Order Received =>
   at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.getEventAppExecutionExceptionSize(SessionDataWriter.java:597)
   at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.getEventAppExecutionExceptionSize(SessionDataWriter.java:600)
   at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.getEventAppExecutionExceptionSize(SessionDataWriter.java:600)
   at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.getEventAppExecutionSize(SessionDataWriter.java:533)
   at com.crashlytics.android.SessionDataWriter.getEventAppSize(SessionDataWriter.java:492)
   at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.writeSessionEvent(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:956)
   at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.access$200(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:56)
   at com.crashlytics.android.CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler$7.call(CrashlyticsUncaughtExceptionHandler.java:274)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils$1$1.onRun(ExecutorUtils.java:58)
   at io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.BackgroundPriorityRunnable.run(BackgroundPriorityRunnable.java:13)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Comment: Hi Scott. Any possibility of knowing Android version, RxJava version, RxAndroid version, please? Are you properly disposing all your subscriptions?

Comment: io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0
io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.12
`Android version 5.1`
And yes I am unsubscribing all of my subscriptions and then settineg them to null

Comment: Can you try RxAndroid 1.0.1https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid/releases/tag/v1.0.1 please?

Comment: Thanks @IvanMorgillo I will do that and see if this is still happening. Thank you

Answer (score 52, accepted):

What's happening is that your `onError` implementation in a `Subscriber` is throwing an unchecked exception which is against the Observable contract and this aborts the observable processing throwing an `OnErrorFailedException` in the `observeOn` scheduler.

Comment: It's worth pointing on that if you try to debug this by logging inside your `onError` implementation, you may not see it in logcat. You are best debugging with breakpoints. This is what kept me from initially seeing the problem.

Comment: How can I track the exact error in `onError()` callback instead of receiving this generic stacktrace?

Comment: How to fix this?

Comment: how to fix? You are receiving a Throwable in your implementation of onError and then causing another error in the processing of that error. I would fix your implementation so it does not do that. To help you debug you could log the thrown error by wrapping your onError implementation with try catch.

Answer (score 14):

You are probably passing an Activity context somewhere from your `onError` callback.  This was happening to me when I tried to show an AlertDialog - passing to it a specific Activity context - and pressing back button before that dialog came up.  My advice is to not pass Activity contexts this way.

Comment: this sounds rather like a very specific case

Comment: @CarloLópezScutaro What is causing the problem for you?

Comment: This happened to me. Exact same scenario. How did you end up creating the dialog? I have my dialog creation abstracted out to a util class so I need to pass it a Context to create the AlertDialog.

Comment: ok, but if we need ti create a dialog when `onError` is called?

Comment: @Choletski try to wrap your code with `if(activity != null && isAdded()){ }` if you show the dialog from the fragment. It should prevent IllegalStateException for this case.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I solved the issue:

```
public abstract class MyNetworkSubscriber<T> extends Subscriber<T> {

@Override
public void onCompleted() {}

@Override
public void onError(Throwable e) {
    if (e instanceof HttpException) {
        ResponseBody responseBody = ((HttpException) e).response().errorBody();
        try {
            if (responseBody != null) {
                MyError error = new Gson().fromJson(responseBody.string(), MyError.class);
                onErrorCode(error);
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void onErrorCode(MyError error){};
}
```

For some reason, OkHttp was forcing me to catch onError so I did. If I did not do this, OkHttp/Retrofit will crash and the app will shut down.

By providing this solution,

1. you can choose to override your own `onErrorCode` and get a more detailed object back as error which comes from your API but you don't have to.
2. OnError is overridden, no more crazy crashes.
3. And last but not least it is still generic because of `<T>`!

You can also force onComplete & onError to be overriden to make the methods abstract.

Answer (score 0):

if you want update UI in onError,just try:

```
api.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Subscriber(){....})
```